# Autorellenar un campo de mi modelo con datos del mismo modelo

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Hola estoy tratando de crear un formulario donde uno de los campos se auto rellene con datos de otros campos.

El modelo posee el campo QR el cual se tiene que auto rellenar con la palabra uPDN + el campo id, quedando el campo QR de un usuario con id 1 como `uPDN000001`.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es la creación del formulario pero no se como auto completar el campo QR.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
TIPOUSUARIO= [
    ('Conductor', 'Conductor'),
    ('Dependiente', 'Dependiente'),
]
nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=32)  # Field name made lowercase.
tipousuario = models.CharField(db_column='TipoUsuario', max_length=23, choices=TIPOUSUARIO, default='Conductor')  # Field name made lowercase.
movil = models.CharField(db_column='Movil', max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
qr = models.CharField(db_column='QR', max_length=12)  # Field name made lowercase.
pin = models.IntegerField(db_column='PIN')  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class UsuariospdnForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuariospdn
        fields = ['nombre', 'tipousuario', 'movil','qr','pin']
        labels = {
            'nombre': 'Nombre del UsuarioPDN',
            'tipousuario': 'Tipo de Usuariopdn',
            'movil': 'Teléfono móvil',
            'qr': 'Código QR',
            'pin':'Pin del UsuarioPDN'
        }
        widgets ={
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese el nombre del usuariopdn',
                    'id': 'nombre'
                }
            ),
            'tipousuario': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'tipousuario'
                }
            ),
            'movil': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese el numero te teléfono móvil',
                    'id': 'movil'
                }
            ),
            'qr': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese el código QR del usuariopdn',
                    'id': 'qr'
                }
            ),
            'pin': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese el pin del usuariopdn',
                    'id': 'pin'
                }
            )
        }
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class CrearUsuariosPDN(CreateView):
    model = Usuariospdn
    template_name = 'GestionPaqueteria/usuariospdn/crear_usuariospdn.html'
    form_class = UsuariospdnForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('gestionpaqueteria:listar_usuariospdn')
```

Existe alguna funcionalidad para poder auto rellenar el campo QR con la palabra uPDN + el el numero de id.

Comment: Necesitas obligatoriamente que se rellene el campo QR en el form? O basta con realizar dicha acción al momento en que se guarda la instancia?. Por ejemplo utilizado el método  `save()` del modelo.

Comment: Etonces tendría que editar la función en mi vista verdad? podrías ponerme un ejemplo de como podria ser la función es que soy nuevo y solo he trabajado con las vistas básicas

Comment: Por ejemplo, poner lo siguiente en el método `save()`: `self.qr = 'uPDN' + self.id`, de esta manera cuando se guarde o se cree la instancia, el valor del campo QR, sera `uPDN1`, dependiendo el id.

Comment: Y no hará falta ninguna modificasion en el form, ni siquiera sera necesario mostrar el campo QR.

Comment: Hola realice el cambio al método `save()` como sugeriste, pero lo que me guarda es uPDNNone, es decir, no me esta guardando la palabra uPDN con el id. Así fue como lo hice, `def save(self):
        self.qr = 'uPDN'+str(self.pk)
        super (Usuariospdn, self).save()`

Comment: Ya publique mi respuesta con la solución, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el campo `qr` tenga el valor por defecto de `uPDN + id`, propuse utilizar el método `save()`, pero no se puede ya que aun se no se crea la instancia por lo cual no existe el `id` o `pk` (Me olvide de ese aspecto).

Para hacerlo tendríamos que utilizar señales, de la siguiente manera:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender = MyModel) # Registramos la señal
def set_qr_field(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Entramos al if si esta creada la instancia
    if kwargs.get('created'):
        # Actualisamos la instancia
        sender.objects.filter(id = instance.id).update(qr = 'uPDN' + str(instance.id))
```

De esta manera cada ves que se crea una instancia el valor de `qr` sera `'uPDN'` mas el `id`.

No hará falta mostrar el campo `qr` en el formulario, pues tendrá el valor deseado ya por defecto.

La señal puedes ponerla en el archivo `models.py` o en uno nuevo llamado `signals.py`, si quieres guardarlo en el archivo `signals.py`, tienes que registrar las señales en el archivo `apps.py` en el método [`ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready), importando las señales.

Si quieres saber mas sobre el tema de señales, visita la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/). Espero haberte ayudado.

Mas informacion:

- Decorador [`receiver()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions).
- Señal [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save).

Comment: Perfecto, lo acabo de probar y trabaja maravillosamente bien, gracias por la ayuda y la documentación adicional

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte!